# PHP composer autoload not loading class

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I'm just getting started using composer for dependency management and I'm having a hard time figuring out how I'm not adhering to psr-4 for autoloading so I'm here for advice. I've got a class that generates random values that is already on the packagist. The project structure is the following (I've labeled the composer.json files A and B):

project dir

```
  |classfile.php 
A |composer.json
  |vendor
   |autoload.php
    |ejfrancis
      |php-random-value
B       |composer.json
        |RandomValue.php        <--the class I want autoloaded
```

composer.json A

```
{
    "require": {
        "ejfrancis/php-random-value": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

composer.json B

```
{
    "name": "ejfrancis/php-random-value",
    "description": "Secure random value generator.",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"        
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ejfrancis\\" : ""
        }
    }
}
```

and finally the RandomValue.php file, which declares the ejfrancis namespace

```
namespace ejfrancis;

class RandomValue{
  //foo
}
```

When I run the app I get an error 'class RandomValue not found', so it's not autoloading correctly. Am I not complying to psr-4, or is there something else I'm doing wrong? I've also tried autoloading just using a composer classmap like `"classmap" : ["RandomValue.php"]` to no success. 
Thanks for the help

Update: I've run 'composer validate' on the composer.json B file, it definitely is valid

Comment: How does the code look like that creates that error you mention? As I see it, you most likely missed to use the correct namespace there, everything else looks good.

Comment: looks like you're correct! the code was '$randomValue = new RandomValue', I added 'use ejfrancis\RandomValue as RandomValue' at the top of the classfile it's being used in and now it works. if you add this as a full answer and not a comment, I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 17):

Change in your composer to `"Namespace\\"` and do a composer `dump-autoload -o`

Comment: I changed my autoload psr-4 attribute in composer.json B to "ejfrancis\\": "" and ran 'composer dump-autoload -o', still says class not found

Comment: I've also run 'composer validate' on the composer.json B, it's definitely valid. you were correct about the trailing '\\'

Comment: Thanks @ejfrancis for that composer command, it helped me see that my composer file was not formatted properly

Comment: this saved m day although i was late to find it

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem recently and after struggling for an hour, I found out that I haven't used the `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php;` in  the project initial file.

I just sent this answer for whom forgot this part like me.