# PHP Project Composer autoload can't find the classes

Tags: class, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I'm building an authentication system and I use Composer to manage dependencies.
When I run my project it seems none of the classes can be found. I generated the files using cmd. I found similar threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24392787/php-composer-autoload-not-loading-class) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044288/composer-autoload-cant-find-class) but it does not quite do it... Any idea?

The error

> Fatal error: Class 'Bixxcom\User\User' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\authentication\app\start.php on line 34

start.php

```
<?php
use Slim\Slim;
use Slim\Views\Twig;
use Slim\Views\TwigExtension;
use Noodlehaus\Config;
use Bixxcom\User\User;
use Bixxcom\Helpers\Hash;

session_cache_limiter(false);
session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

define('INC_ROOT', dirname(__DIR__));

require INC_ROOT . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Slim([
    'mode' => file_get_contents(INC_ROOT . '/mode.php'),
    'view' => new Twig(),
      'templates.path' => INC_ROOT . '/app/views'
]);

$app->configureMode($app->config('mode'), function() use ($app){

    $app->config = Config::load(INC_ROOT .  "/app/config/{$app->mode}.php");

        });

        require 'database.php';
          require 'routes.php';

        $app->container->set('user', function(){
            return new User;
        }  );

                $app->container->singleton('hash', function() use ($app){
                    return new Hash ($app->config);
        });


        $view = $app->view();
        $view->parserOptions = [
            'debug'  => $app->config->get('twig.debug')
   ];

           $view->parserExtensions = [
               new TwigExtension
           ];
```

composer.json

```
{

    "autoload":{
        "psr-4":{
            "Bixxcom\\":  "app/Bixxcom"
        }
    },


    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*",
        "slim/slim": "~2.0",
        "slim/views": "0.1.*",
        "twig/twig": "~1.0",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~5.2",
        "hassankhan/config": "0.8.*",
        "illuminate/database": "~5.0",
        "ircmaxell/random-lib": "~1.1"
    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php
namespace Bixxcom\User;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

 class User extends Eloquent
 {
     protected $table = 'users';

     protected $fillable = [
             'username',
             'password',
             'active',
             'active_hash',
             'recover_hash',
             'remember_user',
             'remember_token',
             'first_name',
             'last_name',
             'age',
             'email',
             'phone',
             'address',
             'city',
            'country'
     ];
 }
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried ```composer dump-autoload```?

Comment: @timbroder: Yes. The autoload.php file generates in vendor folder. Should I place it one level up?

Comment: that's the right place for it. Can you post ```User.php```?

Comment: @timbroder : file uploaded.